# Loop Over Array of Lat Lng for Google Maps API

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to map a set of 100+ addresses with weighting that is dynamic from my database. If I render my map with all points and weighting hardcoded it will work, but it keeps giving me an error when I try to create the objects in a for loop.

```
Type 'object[]' is not assignable to type '(LatLng | WeightedLocation)[]'.
    Type 'object' is not assignable to type 'LatLng | WeightedLocation'.
      Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type 'WeightedLocation': location, weight
```

Data is structured as follows.

```
[{
  "_id": "123",
  "bounds": { "lat": 37, "lng": -122 },
  "val1": 0,
  "val2": 18
}, {
  "_id": "124",
  "bounds": { "lat": 38, "lng": -123 },
  "val1": 5,
  "val2": 100
}]
```

the function that is giving me the error is

```
function getPoints() {
  const data = getDataFromDB();
  var heatData : object[] = [];

  data.forEach(r => {
    console.log(r.bounds)
    const loc = new google.maps.LatLng(r.bounds.lat, r.bounds.lng)
    const newObj = {location: loc, weight: r.val1}
    heatData.push(newObj);
  })
  console.log(heatData) 

  
  return heatData;
}
```

Edit to add.

When I pass this array the map will render. I just cannot figure out how create this array but with data I provide and not hardcoded.

```
var heatData = [
    {location: new google.maps.LatLng(37.782, -122.447), weight: 100},
    {location: new google.maps.LatLng(37.782, -122.443), weight: 2},
    {location: new google.maps.LatLng(37.782, -122.441), weight: 3},
    {location: new google.maps.LatLng(37.782, -122.439), weight: 2},
    {location: new google.maps.LatLng(37.782, -122.435), weight: 0.5},
    {location: new google.maps.LatLng(37.785, -122.447), weight: 3},
    {location: new google.maps.LatLng(37.785, -122.445), weight: 2},
    {location: new google.maps.LatLng(37.785, -122.441), weight: 0.5},
    {location: new google.maps.LatLng(37.785, -122.437), weight: 2},
    {location: new google.maps.LatLng(37.785, -122.435), weight: 3}
  ];
```

Comment: How does your `LatLng` and `WeightedLocation` look? It seems Typescript is complaining about the elements in `heatData` is not compatible with either of those.

Comment: Is `heatData` supposed to be an array? Why are defining it like that?

Answer (score 0):

I think you intended to type `heatData` as `(LatLng | WeightedLocation)[]` instead of `object[]`:

```js
var heatData : (LatLng | WeightedLocation)[] = [];
```

Answer (score 0):

Just replace

```
var heatData : object[] = [];
```

with

```
const heatData = [];
```

And it would do.